# Cpanel php version != .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

The company where we have been renting webspace from for years stops its activities. The website was automatically transferred to a company that takes over the existing customers.

The new company does not offer multiphp via cpanel for shared hosting. 1 of the subdomains gives the following problem:

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version "> = 7.3.0".

I changed the PHP version for the full site to 7.3 via cpanel, but the problem remains. I checked via phpinfo () and the php version turns out to be 7.2.34.

In .htaccess it says:

```
# php - BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
   AddHandler application / x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php - END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit "
```

I guess the problem is there? Can I manually edit in .htaccess? And what exactly should be there?

Answer (score 0):

If your host supports php7.3 then you can update your htaccess as follows

```
# php - BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
   AddHandler application / x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php - END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit "
```

If that gives you a white screen error, then you'll need to contact the hosting provider.

Comment: Just keep in mind that cPanel may later change this back to ea-php72 at really unpredictable times. The better solution to your problem may be to switch providers.

Comment: I think the problem might be that my previous provider offered multiphp for shared hosting and the new one doesn't.

I updated the global php version and commented out the AddHandler line in the subdomain .htaccess files and that solves the problem.